# Is there another meaning to prototype?

Tags: terminology

I am reading [Pro C#](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590598849).  It says

> do be aware that the value 0 is automatically returned, even if you construct a Main() method prototyped to return void.

What does prototyped mean in this context?

The only C# related definition of a prototype I'm aware of has to do with a model or test program tossed together without the intention to go to production.

Comment: What about javascript prototypes? Ever hear about them?

Comment: @Oded oh yea, sure.  Though, that certainly doesn't apply here.

Comment: Just making the point ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, I believe the phrase is used a as synonym to a method signature.

You can call any method signature the prototype of the actual call.

A bit of a throwback to c and header files.

See wikipedia - [Function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype):

> A function prototype in C, Perl or C++ is a declaration of a function that omits the function body but does specify the function's return type, name, arity and argument types. While a function definition specifies what a function does, a function prototype can be thought of as specifying its interface.